# Exceeded Maximum Execution Time error in GAS despite script only running for 40 seconds (and running fine moments before)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm not sure what kind of background to give, I'm really just looking for some insight perhaps on the reason I'm getting this error. I have a feeling it has to do with quotas, but if so, the wording is terribly misleading and making it impossible for me to get answers.

Here is an example of the error:

[16-11-03 23:42:54:915 PDT] Execution failed: Exceeded maximum execution time [39.823 seconds total runtime]

Every function that once worked in my sheet is now spitting the same type of error, from the simplest onEdit functions to the more complex Menu Triggers (hence why I believe it to be a quota limit). I've been testing some fixes to a few aspects of the sheet all day and this just error kicked and now I can't do anything :/

Extra background:

- I have some time-driven triggers running and each of them also have the option to be run manually (through a menu option)
- One such script took quite a while longer to run than usual right before I got this error

If it's helpful I can also provide some of the script in question, but I don't believe it's particular to the code.

Comment: Is this when running it manually or by trigger?

Comment: most likely refers to total DAILY time. google apps script quotas.

Comment: This happens when running manually. (either on edit or a menu button)

Comment: @ZigMandel The daily time limit per Google's Guide is 6 hr / day (Trigger TOTAL Runtime) and the "Triggers" limit is 20 / user / script.
I'm not sure what that last one means by "Triggers" but the message I get seems to be related to TIME.

Comment: Are your scripts working again?

Comment: They are- I got around the issue (presumably) by turning the onEdit function into an installable trigger which has a longer time limit. Ideally onEdit type functions wouldn't take more than 30 seconds, but in this case, where running larger functions seemed to "slow down" my bandwidth, sometimes they do and I still want them to run.

Answer (score 1):

Simple triggers like onEdit and onOpen, and also custom spreadsheet functions are limited to 30 seconds.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I didn't realize that onEdit was a simple trigger.